# What is a smart way to check if a string variable value is one of a specified set of value in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a simple C#.NET application where I have an if condition where I am checking if a string variable value is a string or another string or another string or another one, etcetc.

Something like this:

```
if(protocollo == "2019/0002391" || protocollo == "2019/0002390" || protocollo == "2019/0001990" || ........)
```

This solution works but it is not so elegant. What could be a smarter way to implement the same behavior?

Comment: I think this would be a better fit on [codereview.se]

Comment: It depends on what you're doing with the check. A `switch`, a `Dictionary` that maps to something, a `HashSet`, an `enum` or reading values from a file/database are all possible alternatives, differing in speed/memory/readability/maintainability/what have you.

Comment: Maybe saving it in a List and then check it once, or maybe there is a LINQ for that (not sure).

Comment: Create a list or array of items and then use `Contains()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @JeroenMostert that it really depends on the context of the rest of your application. That said, using an array of strings and checking if your string is in there is a nice straightforward solution. There are certianily solutions that would scale better, take a look at [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8).

```
string[] s = new string[] { "2019/0002391", "2019/0002390", "2019/0001990", ... };

if (s.Contains(protocollo)) {
    // fill in here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never said, so I'm making the assumption that the strings you're checking against is hard-coded and not something that changes often. To that end, you could create a `string[]` or `HashSet<string>` in a static class so it only initializes the one time, then expose a method for checking a second string against the valid ones.

```csharp
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Protocols.ValidProtocol("2019/0002391")); //True
    Console.WriteLine(Protocols.ValidProtocol("2018/0000000")); //False
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static class Protocols
{
    public static bool ValidProtocol(string protocol)
    {
        return _validProtocols.Contains(protocol);
    }

    private static readonly HashSet<string> _validProtocols = new HashSet<string>
    {
        "2019/0002391",
        "2019/0002390",
        "2019/0001990"
        //etc, etc...
    };
}
```

A solution like this would probably not be ideal if the list of `string`s you need to check against changes often. You'd probably want to pull the list from an external source like a file or a database if you need to modify it often.

Answer (score 0):

I had some code similar to your example in a static extension method. I didn't want to have to instantiate an array every time the method was called, but I wanted to improve the readability of the code.

I improved the code using the [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) which was added in C# 8. Here is the what your example might look like if implemented with a switch expression. Depending on what your code does if the condition is true you may be able to improve on this, but this is the basics.

```
var isProtocolloMatch = protocollo switch
{
    "2019/0002391" => true,
    "2019/0002390" => true,
    "2019/0001990" => true,
    _ => false
};

if (isProtocolloMatch)
{
    // do stuff
}
```